# Enable Content Type Auditing with PowerShell

Tags: content-type, auditing, information-management, information-policy

In the browser, you can go into a Site Content Type's Information Management Policy Settings and decide to audit specific things about this content type.

How can this be configured using the SharePoint Object Model? Is there any way to set this using PowerShell?

Thanks

Comment: Google search leads me to http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/11/12/programmatically-set-retention-policy-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Thanks @NadeemYousuf, that's pretty close but not quite there. I wasnt able to find that link myself.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the following articles.

[Add an auditing policy feature to a content type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262931(v=office.12).aspx)

[Configure Audit Settings for SharePoint 2013 Sites](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/07/enable-audit-logs-in-sharepoint-2013-using-powershell.html)

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but this is a terrible answer. 1) This site discourages link-only answers. We don't want to become like technet forums where every answer is a link to another answer which is a link to another answer! Please summarize the pertinent parts of the linked pages. 2) The first link does indeed discuss what I'm talking about, but there is no mention of the Object Model or PowerShell. 3) The second link is indeed using PowerShell, but it is about Audits in general, not on Content Types.